# How to force IIS server to remove the html base tag

Tags: html, iis

I'm using Visual WebGui to develop Web application, How can I force IIS to change the html base tag in the html file?

Answer (score 1):

IIS serves files, so unless the file it serves has an `<html>` root tag it won't serve it.
It you are using .net, change the `<html>` tag in the template.

Also: Why would you want to?

If you are trying to send xml files, you can just have:

```
<xml>
    <html>
        <body>
        </body>
    </html>
</xml>
```

No need to remove the tag.

Answer (score 1):

IIS won't do this by itself. In order to accomplish this you would have to develop your own custom ISAPI filter (or find a 3rd party ISAPI dll that already does this).

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524610.aspx